# background image grayscale

Tags: html, css

I for background on my website I use colors and at top I have an image.
I want to make this image black and white with css:

```
body {
    background: url('background.jpg') center top no-repeat;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

but this code make whole site grayscale

I also tried to put site content to new div with style `-webkit-filter: none;` but it don't work neither.

Comment: From what I can understand from your code you are using selectors for whole body. Now you are choosing a background for the body - which is your actual visible website right? What are you actually expecting then?

Comment: You have an image on top which should be in grayscale or the background?

Answer (score 2):

There's another solution without using an overlay div using `background-blend-mode`.

This is supported among all major browsers https://caniuse.com/?search=background-blend-mode (except IE)

```
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
background: url('background.jpg') center top no-repeat;
background-blend-mode: luminosity;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try a different div overlayed over `<body>`
like this

```
#overlay {
    background: url('background.jpg') center top no-repeat;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0.5; /*make it as your requirement*/
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

and your html will look like

```
<body>
    <div id="overlay"></div>
    <!-- other body elements -->
</body>
```

Answer (score -2):

This is block style in jsx syntax (from reactjs-application). I have no clue what is going on there, but it seems to work

```
            style={{
                minHeight: '100vh',
                backgroundPosition: 'center',
                backgroundSize: 'cover',
                backgroundImage:"linear-gradient(black, black), url('images/bgimage.jpg')",
                backgroundBlendMode: 'saturation'
            }}
```

Comment: He never said he's using reactjs or any js framework

Comment: He does not need to. This is just jsx syntax code, he can use standard js or css syntax if he wants to.